# Why does function return undefined when it explicitly is told to return true?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to solve the following coding exercise.

> We have two special characters. The first character can be represented
>   by one bit 0. The second character can be represented by two bits (10
>   or 11).
>
> Now given a string represented by several bits. Return whether the
>   last character must be a one-bit character or not. The given string
>   will always end with a zero.
>
> example:
>
> Input:  bits = [1, 0, 0] Output: True

Below is my solution for the above challenge. Why is this returning `undefined`? If I use [1,0,1,0] as input, it should return `true` but I am getting `undefined`. I am explicitly writing `true` in the return statement and not the results of a variable.

```
var isOneBitCharacter = function(bits) {
  console.log(bits);
    var length = bits.length;

    if (length == 1) {
      return true;
    }
    if (length == 0) {return false;}

    if (length == 2 && bits[0] === 1) {
      return false;
    }
    if (bits[0] === 1) {
      isOneBitCharacter(bits.slice(1));
    } else {
      isOneBitCharacter(bits.slice(2));
    }
};
isOneBitCharacter([1,0,1,0]);
```

Comment: you're not returning anything from recursive calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are missing returns. Here is adjusted code:

```
var isOneBitCharacter = function(bits) {
  console.log(bits);
    var length = bits.length;

    if (length == 1) {
      return true;
    }
    if (length == 0) {return false;}

    // added return here and next statements
    if (length == 2 && bits[0] === 1) {
      return false;
    }
    if (bits[0] === 1) {
      return isOneBitCharacter(bits.slice(1));
    } else {
      return isOneBitCharacter(bits.slice(2));
    }
};
isOneBitCharacter([1,0,1,0]);
```

Comment: Ah. So i guess you have to return the recursive call. I thought you could just call the function.

Comment: Yes, you have to. No other way around :)